# Shade Netting Car Port - has a small tear - how to stop it from getting bigger?

Tags: repair

Is there a way to "repair" or stop a small hole in a shade netting car port from getting bigger?

Comment: netting repair: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=cGP&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=netting+repair&oq=netting+repair&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30l3j0i5i30l6.16502.20910.0.21565.8.8.0.0.0.0.238.1161.1j6j1.8.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..2.6.760.NSV0mYixNQc

Answer (score 1):

Depends in part on why it has a hole.

If it's old and getting degraded by the sun, it will just tear somewhere else, and wholesale replacement is going to be the best option.

If it was cut by something but is in generally good shape, you can sew a patch to it, overlapping the holed/torn area. You MAY also be able to just melt the edges if it's a small hole.

Comment: Probably too late in the year, go down to your local nursery supply to see if you can get some. They sell the stuff by the roll and possibly by the foot. Sew it on as a patch for now. If this isn't a woopsie, but due to the fact that the car port netting has had several years of exposure, prepare for total replacement next spring.